# console.log() in jade not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I thought I can simply put 
`-console.log('hello')` everywhere I want in jade? It doesn't appear though, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `script.` tag if you haven't already, see the example for buffered code here: http://jade-lang.com/reference/code/.